# Why does chrome enlarge empty object tags?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

So I just fixed a bug on my website because of this - chrome enlargest empty s to 300x150px while firefox doesn't. I made a minimal page to demonstrate the difference: https://riedler.wien/test/chrobject.html ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20210307095251/https://riedler.wien/test/chrobject.html)). I can also post screenshots on request, but I'm assuming that every webdev has both installed.

```css
object{
  background-color:#Fa0;
}
```

```html
<a>Test</a>
<object></object>
<a>Toast</a>
<object>saas</object>
```

I can't find anything about this being the intended behaviour, but I couldn't find a bug report regarding this either. Note that I haven't tested the behaviour of other browsers, but since almost all base off of cromium, I assume they share their behaviour with chrome. Also, the mobile versions of chrome and firefox share the behaviour of their desktop counterparts.

Is this a shortcoming of Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: 300x150px is the default size of replaced elements without intrinsic size defined. For instance <canvas> <svg> <iframe> all do default to 300x150px. I guess the interop issue here is that <object> can be *not* a replaced element, when it has content directly, but it can also be a replaced element, when it has its `data` attribute set. Here we are in the weird case in the middle... I didn't check the specs yet, but I guess it's a gray area that may need a specs issue and WPT tests. However, for you, I wonder why you are using this tag at all.

Comment: Ps: given how [plugins have been removed from the standards](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6003), and the continuous [willing to deprecate both <object> and <plugin>](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4961#issuecomment-539341236), I doubt anything would be fixed there, and you should seriously reconsider your use of this tag.

Comment: aye, I don't remember why I was using this tag at all, but I wanted to rebuild my table with grid for a long time, so I'll remove it eventually. Today is however not this day.

Answer (score -1):

That is just the brower defaults. When building websites, it's generally good to clear all formatting with:

```
* {
    
}
```

Or to reset it all to some sensible default:

```
* {
    all: initial
}
```

Do this at the beginning of the file. This will ensure consistent formatting on every browser.

This is not really a shortcomming of either browser, it's a compromise, as some websites need this, others don't. But generally, the way firefox does it is the best way. In the end you'll want it to work best on chrome, because almost every browser is based on it and it has the largest userbase.

Comment: a) this doesn't even work
b) this is very much bad practice and fucks up the style of the whole website

and c) I want to break chromes market share, so, if I have the choice between supporting firefox and supporting chrome, I'll always go for firefox.